# Nil error when presenting UIView in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiview

I am trying to create a view which gets presented from a UIViewController.  To do this, I have created a subclass of a UIView (OnboardingCaptureView.swift), and a .xib interface file to go with it.  In my interface, I have a label, called alertLabel.  And in my init method in my OnboardingCaptureView class, I am setting 4 parameters, and setting the label to the string parameter, message.

For some reason, when I allocate this view and add it as a subview, it crashes and says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  When I remove this label, it crashes in my required init? method.  I have no idea why I can't create and present a simple subclass of the UIView.  I have a feeling that Xcode is bugging out on me, but I've built, cleaned derived data, and restarted multiple times.  Is there something wrong with my code?

```
//Custom UIView subclass
class OnboardingCaptureView: UIView {

@IBOutlet private weak var alertLabel: UILabel!

    init(triangleXOffset: CGFloat, closeButtonOnTop: Bool, message: String, frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);
        //Crashes at next line, claims self.alertLabel is nil
        self.alertLabel.text = message
    
        connectNibUI()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //If i disconnect the alertLabel outlet and remove it, it crashes here
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

```
//Creating and adding subview 
let onboardingCaptureView = OnboardingCaptureView(triangleXOffset: 0, closeButtonOnTop: true, message: "Alert", frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,200))
self.onboardingView = onboardingCaptureView
self.view.addSubview(onboardingCaptureView)
```

//EDIT -> connectNibUI method

```
extension UIView {

func connectNibUI() {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(self.dynamicType), bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
    let nibView = nib.first as! UIView
    nibView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    self.addSubview(nibView)
    nibView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.edges.equalTo(self)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems likely your `alertLabel` hasn't actually been assigned.
First, just double check to make sure you actually linked the outlet to the nib.

What actually seems like the issue here is that your custom view is being created, but the nib isn't. What's going on in your `connectNibUI()` function?  If that's where you're loading in the nib, all you may need to do is set the label text after that function.

Comment: Hey Wyatt, I've edited my code to with connectNibUI function.

Comment: And the alert label has been assigned, verified multiple times

Comment: Have you tried setting the label text after calling `connectNibUI()`?  `alertLabel` will be nil until the nib has been created.

Comment: yes.  when i do that, it generated this error-> fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file /Users/joshuaoconnor/Desktop/timeloop_ios/TimeLoop/UI/VideoCapture/CaptureOnboardingView.swift, line 26

Comment: FINALLY.  the issue was that I hooked up the .xib interface to the class (OnboardingCaptureView).  I think this was creating a retain cycle and crashign the app

Comment: I don't have my code in front of me, but when implementing custom UIViews in the past I believe i had to implement initWithCoder because it gets called when creating your nib (if the view's custom class property is the same as your subclass).   The error you're seeing is just from the auto-generated initWithCoder.